# running cli php application on mac terminal

Tags: php, terminal, command-line-interface

i want to make php cli application on mac, which is not problem, i have php 7 cli installed and usable. But when im using application it won't read variable properly from my command. My code is:

```
<?
echo 'Zadajte príkaz: ';
$line = fgets(STDIN);

switch($line) {
    case 'tomas':
        echo 'menu pre tomas';
        break;
    case 'veronika':
        echo 'menu pre veronika';
        break;
    default: echo 'Nezadal si správnu hodnotu';
}
?>
```

it won't load even in if.... in if code looks like:

```
<?
echo 'Zadajte príkaz: ';
$line = fgets(STDIN);

if($line == 'tomas'){
   echo 'success';
}else{
   echo 'denied'; }
?>
```

Comment: My assumption would be that this has to do with your php ini. You can try changing your opening tags to <?php or updating your configuration to enable short open tags. In php 7 this was by default disabled and discouraged per documentation.

Comment: it is not in php.ini. I already tried to extend my tags